# What does 60 FPS mean In Flutter How one Screen has 60 Frame per second

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, widget, frame-rate

I am so confused with this concept of 60 FPS, I do understand when you are running a video, the system is rendering/processing 60 images in one second and displaying to make it feel of video but when it comes to a mobile screen/design, it already has one screen UI means one picture how flutter is rendering 60 FPS does it mean it renders the same screen 60 times but why would it render 60 times then,

I am considering one Screen on the flutter mobile application is one image is that correct? if yes then what is the concept of 60 FPS?
Please help me out to get rid of this confusion thanks in advance

Comment: FPS applies to animations, including scrolling.

Comment: so what if we have only simple widgets and not animations ,then 60FPS will not be applied ?

Comment: yes, if you have "static" widgets (without any animations) and there is no interaction with them (by finger pressing or dragging) then no frames will be drawn (you can check it in your logs by setting `debugPrintBeginFrameBanner = true;`)